# reported error when python-api connecting to DolphinDB server

Tags: python, dolphindb

reported error when check in database, code as follow

```
import dolphindb as ddb
s = ddb.session()
s.connect("localhost", 24115,"admin", "123456")
x = s.loadTable(tableName="pt",dbPath="dfs://db1")
```

error message below

```
C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dolphindb\session.py:69: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return self.cpp.run(script, *args)
```

why

Answer (score 1):

This warning will be reported when the following statement is executed:

```py
x = s.loadTable(tableName="pt",dbPath="dfs://db1")
```

The warning is caused by a high version of numpy. It won’t affect the normal features and will be canceled by downgrade the numpy version.